# how to search current date in mysql database that store standard date as ('Y-m-d H:i:s')?

Tags: mysql, date, select

I store standard date ( with this format: ('Y-m-d  H:i:s') ) in mysql database, now i want to select records that match this standard date with current date, in other word i want to select the rows where standard_date field demonstrate today's date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `DATE()` to strip off time in the datetime column. `CURDATE()` returns the current date.

```
SELECT *
FROM   tableName
WHERE  DATE(standard_date) = CURDATE()
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo** (*DATE() vs without DATE()*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a943/4)

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
select * from mytable where date(standard_date) = curdate();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from tablename where date = CURDATE()
```

> CURDATE() returns the current date.

Answer (score 0):

If you use DATE type, use [CURDATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) function -

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE date_field = CURDATE()
```

If you use DATETIME type, use CURDATE() function and [DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function to get date part from datetime value -

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE(date_time_field) = CURDATE()
```